# Need Help Identifying Cause of Blue Screen

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I have recently started getting BSOD.

- Environment is Windows 10 x64, with i7 CPU.
- Windows 10 is updated.
- I have tried to update most likely causes, aka Video, and Cisco VPN.
- Still getting issues.
- Have installed BlueScreenViewer, but I am not able to identify root cause.
- This is a work computer, with dual monitors. No games played on it.
- Replaced power supply about a year ago.
- Below is a screen shot from BlueScreen Viewer.
- I believe Cisco VPN was running during all BSOD. I know it was running during the last 3 at least.
- Since this is a work computer, I am on VPN at least 1/2 of the time, if not more.
- VPN is Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Version 3.1.13015. - Antivirus is Avast Free AntiVirus 11.2.2261.
- Last issue was this morning.  Although computer had been up and
  running for a while, I believe the only 'user programs' were VPN and
  MS Outlook 2013. I was literally composing email at time of BSOD.
- I am the only user on the system.
- As to Win10 Anniversary Update, I don't know if I had the issues
  prior to this or not.  My first BSOD was Aug 9.  I know I have
  Anniversary update, but I don't recall installation date.

Any thoughts or ideas appreciated. I plan on running MemTest on it all night tonight. No hardware changes in months.

[image: Blue Screen View]

2nd picture is the details from the latest BSOD.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that your problem had started after the anniversary update?

Comment: The use of windbg, is a crtiical step of information gathering, in a case like this. If you don't know how to use windbng, there is a question with an answer, that explains how to use it.

Comment: share the dmp files

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you provided, it definitely looks like a network driver that is causing the crash.  I suspect that Cisco AnyConnect doesn't work right with the Windows 10 Anniversary update.  This wouldn't be the first time a Cisco driver has caused problems.  Kind of ironic for a network equipment company, wouldn't you say?  ;-)

Anyway, uninstall the AnyConnect client and see if your problems go away.  If they do, then your choices are roll back the Win10 Anniversary Update, or upgrade to a newer version of AnyConnect (they're in the 4.x series now, so yours is old).

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the .dmp file will very likely reveal the cause of the crash. Take a look at [Stu Mackellar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321103/171846) on stackoverflow.